# How do we solve $xa^x = b$ for $x$?

Tags: exponential-function, problem-solving

Consider $x9^x = \frac{3}{2}$. I used wolfram alpha and found its solution to be $x = \frac{1}{2}$. But I don't know the method to get this solution. So, how do we go about solving this problem, mainly the general problem: $xa^x = b$?

Comment: You don't, really, but you can express the solution in terms of the Lambert W function: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is made for the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) which is defined so that
$$W(xe^x)=x$$
There a few standard manipulations to get equations into this standard form. In this case we have
$$xa^x=b$$
$$x e^{x \ln a}=b$$
$$(x \ln a)  e^{x \ln a}=b \ln a$$
$$W((x \ln a)  e^{x \ln a})=W(b \ln a)$$
$$x \ln a=W(b \ln a)$$
$$x =\frac{W(b \ln a)}{\ln a}$$